# In onChange trigger, e.changeType equals EDIT when it should be INSRT_GRID or REMOVE_GRID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with an onChange trigger correctly firing. I created a button which runs a script that creates a new sheet based on a template. When it does, the onChange fires, but the e.changeType equals EDIT, not INSERT_GRID. But when I manually create a sheet in Sheets, e.changeType equals INSERT_GRID.

Another oddity : when i manually delete a sheet I have manually created in sheets, e.changeType equals REMOVE_GRID. But when I manually delete a sheet I have created with the button and my script, e.changeType equals EDIT.

```
function functionOnChangeWIP2(e) {
  Logger.log(e.changeType);
  if (e.changeType == 'REMOVE_GRID') {    
    Logger.log("inside REMOVE_GRID");
  }
  else if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID') {
    Logger.log("inside INSERT_GRID");
}


//function to create a new sheet by pressing a button
function newMonthlySheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ex');
  var newSheetName = "newSheetName";
  ss.insertSheet(newSheetName,1, {template: templateSheet});
}
```

The only trigger I have created in apps script is one for the function functionOnChangeWIP2 to run onChange. It does, but as I said, e.changeType is inconsistent. What should I do to have e.changeType returns REMOVE_GRID and INSERT_GRID consistently ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just facing a limitation of both [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) and [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) triggers:

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run.

There's also a bug [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764617) in Google's issue tracker that confirms this:

> This is working as intended. Changes made to a spreadsheet by a script do not cause triggers to fire. Only changes made in the UI lead to the onChange trigger to fire.

Now, there's a contradiction here, because your trigger is definitely firing, it's just that it's not tracking the exact event type. My guess is that the changes in the UI also create some kind of hidden metadata that script changes do not. This would explain both of the discrepancies that you found: elements created or deleted by scripts do not have the same metadata as the ones created in the UI.

This is not the only place where you can see differences, for example, the [CellImage.getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/cell-image#getUrl()) method only works if the image was inserted via API, so we can clearly see that there are some unseen differences between UI and script changes. Since a consistent behavior cannot be guaranteed, Google seems to have categorized event triggers as "incompatible" with script changes, even though they do at least detect that a change was made.

My advice would be to change your approach. You could just code whatever you want to do on Sheet creation within your `newMonthlySheet()` function. You can also use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to track the current number of Sheets in your Spreadsheet. When the `onChange()` trigger fires you can check it, and if the number is higher it means that an `INSERT_GRID` occurred, if the number is lower it means it was a `REMOVE_GRID`, and no change means that something else happened.

For now you'll need to follow some kind of workaround. You can also consider posting a new feature request in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) so this may be improved in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the workaround you suggested seem to do just as I want.